# PDO inserts wrong values

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo

I am using symfony2 and PDO to insert values to a database.

```
private static function insertAction($action, $conn){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO BANKACTIONS (clientName, actionDate, currency, value, actionType) VALUES (clientName, actionDate, currency, value, actionType)";
            $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array(':clientName'=>$action->getClientName(),
                ':actionDate'=>$action->getDate(),
                ':currency'=>$action->getCurrency(),
                ':value'=>$action->getValue(),
                ':actionType'=>$action->getActionType()));
        }
    }
```

**this is the var_dump for the array**

```
actionarray(5) { [":clientName"]=> string(6) "client" [":currentDate"]=> string(10) "1358200800" [":currency"]=> string(3) "ILS" [":value"]=> string(3) "ILS" [":actionType"]=> string(7) "deposit" }
```

*Which is correct...*

**But when I check the table in myphpadmin**

I get

> id  clientName  actionDate  currency    value   actionType
>
> 1       0   0   0
>             2       0   0   0
>                 3       0   0   0
>             4       0   0   0
>             5       0   0   0
>             6       0   0   0
>             7       0   0   0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this :

```
private static function insertAction($action, $conn){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO BANKACTIONS 
                (clientName, actionDate, currency, value, actionType) 
                VALUES (:clientName, :actionDate, :currency, :value, :actionType)";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(
            'clientName'  => $action->getClientName(),
            'currentDate' => $action->getDate(),
            'currency'    => $action->getCurrency(),
            'value'       => $action->getValue(),
            'actionType'  => $action->getActionType()));
    }
}
```

2 points ":" in the SQL request and nothing in the array ! :)